# VBA code takes long time to execute

Tags: vba, excel

The followinf VBA code takes long time to execute

```
Dim rngCol1 As Range
Dim rngCol2 As Range
Dim myvalue As Long
Dim c As Range

Set rngCol1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reviews").Range("D1:D30" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set rngCol2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("M3")

For Each c In rngCol1
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsError(myvalue = WorksheetFunction.Match(c.Value, rngCol2, 0)) Then
    Else
        c.Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next
```

If this code can be modified to run fast.
or, if any alternative VBA code that can be written to highlight value(in red color) in worksheet "Reviews" of column range "D1:D30" when matches in worksheet "Input" of cell number "M3". Thanks

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` ==> bad idea (when used like that). Errors should be handled, not suppressed. In any event, if your code is working but only too slow, perhaps it would be better to post it on [codereview.se]

Comment: rngCol1 is probably covering way more than you think

Comment: Write a CFR for Reviews!D1:D30 based on `=Input!$M$3`

Comment: @BaileyS - at least 300x more it seems.

Comment: isn't there also something about turning screen updating off during the process and then turning it back on when done?

Comment: Why are you even doing MATCH?  You are comparing one cell to another not searching a range. `If c.value = rngcol2.value then`

Comment: your first range is incorrectly defined  ...  if you have 100 rows used then the range becomes `Range("D1:D30" & 100)`  which is `Range("D1:D30100")`

Answer (score 4):

I would tackle this with a Conditional Formatting Rule.

```
Dim addr As String
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Reviews")
    With .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
        addr = .Cells(1).Address(False, True)
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=and(" & addr & "='Input'!$M$3, not(isblank(" & addr & ")))")
            .Interior.Color = 255    'red
        End With
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using AutoFilter (fast for large data sets)

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowMatches()
    Dim srcVal As Variant, hdr As Long

    srcVal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("M3")

    If Not IsError(srcVal) Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reviews").UsedRange.Columns(4)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & srcVal
            If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 1 Then
                hdr = Abs(.Cells(1) <> srcVal)
                .offset(hdr).Resize(.Rows.Count - hdr, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Only issue I see is that .AutoFilter requires a header row and (if the OP's original coded range can be assumed correct), this will skip the first row.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped - I added the option to include or exclude the header row

Comment: ^^^ THAT is awesome ! Thanks @Jeeped (still clicking on the upvote arrow, but nothing happens...)

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
Dim rngCol1 As Range
Dim rngCol2 As Range
Dim myvalue
Dim c As Range

Set rngCol1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reviews").Range("D1:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set rngCol2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("M3")

For Each c In rngCol1
    myvalue = Application.Match(c.Value, rngCol2, 0)
    If Not IsError(myvalue) Then
        c.Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next
```

**Edited Code:**

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rngCol1 As Range
Dim rngCol2 As Range
Dim myvalue
Dim c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reviews")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
Set rngCol1 = ws1.Range("D1:D" & ws1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set rngCol2 = ws2.Range("M3")

For Each c In rngCol1
    myvalue = Application.Match(c.Value, rngCol2, 0)
    If Not IsError(myvalue) Then
        c.Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: There is no explicit parent worksheet defined for `Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: @dibyendu - as written, this will only work if Reviews is the active worksheet.

Comment: If this VBA code can modified, to run from Input worksheet.

Comment: Jeeped raised a valid point. I have added the tweaked code which will work no matter which sheet is currently active sheet.